# how to tell ransack gem to recognize datepicker US format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search, ransack

How to tell [ransack gem](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/) to translate US format *mm/dd/yyyy* (deffault from [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)) ?

project I'm working on will have several lacales files (UK, US), so UK is simple (just change the datepicker format option) but US format is problem

**Example:**

```
= search_form_for @post do |f|
  f.input :created_at_gt,7
```

[image]

params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"created_at_gt"=>"07/04/2012",....}
```

sql:

```
... `posts`.`created_at` > '2012-04-07 00:00:00') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

(should be created_at > '2012-07-04 00:00:00' )

**Note:** I know I could handle that on controller level,  but I'm  looking for solution where Ransack will automatically pick up locales configuration and parse that way

Comment: ok I found solution: my colleague told me to always send yyyy-mm-dd format to server and just display the date on client side in whatever format user wish. How to do that ?  Add extra hidden field and with JS set  that field to DB format when user chose date with datepicker    ...more in https://gist.github.com/3053409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague told me to always send `yyyy-mm-dd` format to the server and just display the date on client side in whatever format users wish.

Now,how to do that? Add extra hidden field and with JS set that field to DB format when user chooses date with datepicker. More [in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/3053409)

Answer (score 1):

equivalent8, to answer your comment i think you need to add translations for date picker:

```
  date:
    picker_format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    formats:
      input: "%d/%m/%Y"
      default: "%d %b %Y"  
      long: "%A %e %B %Y"
```

but then i am using simple form with the following

```
class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    input_html_options.merge!(:value => 
      I18n.l(@builder.object.send(attribute_name) || Time.now.to_date, :format => :input), 
      :data => { :date_format => I18n.t('date.picker_format')}
    )
    "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options )}".html_safe
  end
end
```

this might help you in your situation

Comment: my comment above is the answer to my problem. The "how to do that?" part of comment was rhetorical question,  I'm answering that in the same comment, but thanks anyway